# How to USB tether on a Samsung Galaxy Tab A?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, usb-tethering

I want to USB tether my Samsung Galaxy Tab A (10 in) to my laptop so that I can use it as a second monitor via SpaceDesk in locations with crappy Wi-Fi. So this question will be about USB tethering, but if you know of a way to reliably use my tablet as a second monitor that doesn't require USB tethering, I'd love to hear it!

The tablet doesn't have cellular connectivity, and perhaps for that reason, USB tethering doesn't appear under Settings / Connections (or anywhere else that I can see). I'm looking for any practical way to enable it. This can involve rooting or installing a modded OS, although of course if there's a more straightforward way, I'd prefer that route.

Comment: For anyone also looking to use Spacedesk when the WiFi is crappy, see my post and answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729541/how-to-use-spacedesk-over-a-wired-connection/48780162#48780162

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable usb tethering through adb shell. Root is needed in order to execute these commands:

After adb setup on your machine (if you haven't already setup adb, please see detailed instructions here: [Download Minimal ADB and Fastboot Tool & Setup guide](https://devs-lab.com/download-minimal-adb-fastboot-tool.html), perform these commands:

> The following commands call
>   `ConnectivityManager.setUsbTethering(boolean enable)` in Android 4:

`adb shell su -c service call connectivity 34 i32 1` turns on USB tethering.

`adb shell su -c service call connectivity 34 i32 0` turns off USB tethering.

(For other Android versions replace `34` with the following `setUsbTethering` calling codes per Android version):

```
5.1.0: 30
6.0.1: 30
7.0.0: 33
```

Credits

[Is it possible to USB tether an android device using adb through the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20226924/7551330)

Comment: Thanks. I did this (using code 33 for Android 7), but the "USB Tethering" option still isn't showing up. Any ideas?

Comment: I think some manufacturers make this feature unavailable due to a variety of reasons probably in favour of carrier specific tethering apps, you may also oversome this using some third party usb tethering apps e.g foxfi, pdanet to mention a few